# Java Transparency: Graphics2D.setComposite(...,alpha) vs. Color(...,alpha)

Tags: java, transparency

I was wondering if there actually a difference between `Graphics2D.setComposite(..., alpha)` and `Graphics2D.setColor(new Color(..., alpha))` when using transparency in Java? How do they affect each other when using a combination of both, e.g.

```
Graphics2D.setComposite(..., 0.5f)
Graphics2D.setColor(new Color(..., 0.5f))
```

It seems that the result is not a transparency of 0.5, but more like 0.25. Is there any recommendation to use one of the previously mentioned approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Graphics2D.setComposite(..., 0.5f)` will effect EVERYTHING that is painted to the `Graphics` context after you apply it.  This includes primitives as well as images.

`Graphics2D.setColor(new Color(..., 0.5f))` will only effect the painting for primitives, every thing else will painted full opaque.

You are right in in the fact that if you paint a color that is 50% transparent onto a `Graphics` context that is 50% transparent will result in a color that appears to be 25% transparent.  The two won't cancel each other out, but will compound.

Think of it this way.

@100% opacity, the color is 50% opaque.
@75% opacity, the color is reduced by 25%, making it 37.5% opaque
@50% opacity, the color is reduced by 50%, making it 25% opaque
@25% opacity, the color is reduced by 75%, making it 12.5% opaque